# Why was Beau in the Murder House?

Tags: plot-explanation, american-horror-story

In season one of American Horror story:

> Larry Harvey (Burned Guy as my girlfriend and I call him) is shown smothering Beau Langdon, at the request of Constance. Beau is chained up in the attic of the Murder House, and continues to exist as a ghost in the house.

But why is Beau in the Murder House? The Langdons didn't live there anymore, Harvey and his family did - the Langdons lived next door, as they do today.  The [wiki entry for Beau](http://americanhorrorstory.wikia.com/wiki/Beauregard_Langdon) (spoilers in link) doesn't offer an explanation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In early 1970's Constance moves to LA to pursue an acting career. It is unclear if she actually moved into the murder house at this time, but in 1984 Constance and her children move out of the Murder house and move next door. So at some point before this her and her husband move into the Murder house.

There is speculation as to why she went next door. Rumors suggest the house doesn't let people leave and only let her leave so she could "work for the house".

In 1993, Larry and his family move into the murder house and after Larry's wife discovers Larry and Constance are having an affair, she kills herself and her children. That's when the Langdons move back into the Murder house with Larry.

If you think about when Tate was shot by the police in 1994, he was in his room in the Murder house (which became Violet's room IIRC), NOT next door in Constance's current house. Why would he have a room if he wasn't living there.

So, Beau was chained in the attic because they in fact were living in the Murder house.

This was a great question because the timelines and events are scattered, vague and hard to piece together. I used a few different resources to come up with this answer. Here are the two significant ones

- [Murder House (story)/Timeline](http://americanhorrorstory.wikia.com/wiki/Murder_House_%28story%29/Timeline)
- [‘American Horror Story’: 10 questions about ‘Open House’](http://www.washingtonpost.com/blogs/celebritology/post/american-horror-story-10-questions-about-open-house/2011/11/16/gIQASIMfUN_blog.html)

Comment: I think I'm going to have to revisit this, because the linked timeline is... significantly different from my understanding. But this makes sense, especially the part about Tate - I didn't think to question his presence in the house. Have a +1 but I'm going to hold off on the accept until this makes more sense to me.

Comment: @mikeTheLiar no problem. The timeline is very confusing and the story is missing pieces (i think deliberately) so somethings have to be inferred using other clues.

Comment: @mikeTheLiar have you been able to piece the timeline together in a way different than mine?

Comment: I think I'm just going to have to watch the whole thing again, with the timeline in front of me. Some of this doesn't mesh with my memories, but I think I might just be mis-remembering/forgetting certain things.

Answer (score 0):

He was in the murder house simply because he died there. If a person dies in the murder house, the ghost of that person is stuck there, regardless of whether that person lived there or not. As in the case of Hayden, even though she didn't live in the murder house, her ghost remained there.

Comment: No, I understand that. My question is why was he chained up in the attic when he was killed, as the timeline implied to me that the Langdons were living next door. However, the other answer points out that they lived in the house at multiple, distinct occasions.

Comment: So what you are trying to imply is that if a person is chained/tied in the murder house, the person's ghost remains chained/tied?

Comment: No, I'm saying that i thought the Langdons lived next door when Beau was killed. I didn't think the new owners would let Constance keep her deformed son chained up in their attic.

Comment: @mikeTheLiar if beau's dead bod was chained in the attic, how come his ghost remained chained on that same spot?

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding the question - it has nothing to do with Beau's ghost. It has to do with _why was he in the house when he was killed_? The show's timeline indicated that Constance, and presumably all of her children, including Beau, lived _next door_ to the Murder House at that point in time, and that the Harveys were living in the Murder House.